# Assign value to new column if substring from a list appears in string

Tags: pandas, list, substring, assign

I have a dataframe df:

```
tags
"a,b,c,d"
"c,q,k,t"
```

and a list of strings I need to search for:

```
searchList =  ["a", "b"]
```

I need to add a new column to my dataframe named "topic".
If a string from searchList appears in column "tags" I need to set the value in that row to bool True, otherwise bool False.

Endresult:

```
tags      | topic
"a,b,c,d" | True
"c,q,k,t" | False
```

My code so far:

```
searchList =  ["a", "b"]
pattern = '|'.join(searchfor)
df["topic"] = df.loc[(df["tags"].str.contains('|'.join(pattern), na=False)), True] = True
```

But I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign mask to new column, also change `pattern` to `searchList`:

```
searchList =  ["a", "b"]
df["topic"] = df["tags"].str.contains('|'.join(searchList), na=False)
print (df)
      tags  topic
0  a,b,c,d   True
1  c,q,k,t  False
```

EDIT:

```
searchList =  ["a", "b"]
df["topic"] = df["tags"].str.split(',', expand=True).isin(searchList).sum(axis=1).eq(2)
print (df)
      tags  topic
0  a,b,c,d   True
1  c,q,k,t  False
2    a,c,d  False
```

**Details**:

First use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for new `DataFrame`:

```
print (df["tags"].str.split(',', expand=True))
   0  1  2     3
0  a  b  c     d
1  c  q  k     t
2  a  c  d  None
```

Then compare by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for membership:

```
print (df["tags"].str.split(',', expand=True).isin(searchList))
       0      1      2      3
0   True   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2   True  False  False  False
```

And count `True`s values by `sum`:

```
print (df["tags"].str.split(',', expand=True).isin(searchList).sum(axis=1))
0    2
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Last compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), `==` for mask.

Comment: Thanks. Can I set a minimal number a list variable has to appear? So "a,b,c" = True (contains 2 values from list) but "a,c,d" = False (contains only 1 value from list?